# Scala + Play, how to get a duration from the HOCON configuration?

Tags: scala, playframework, configuration, hocon

Imagine I have a Duration value defined in my `application.conf` file. The [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Configuration#Duration-format) says it can parse Durations, but I can't see how.

```
timeout = 60 milliseconds
```

Can I parse it directly as a duration value? Ideally I would like to do something like this

```
val timeout = current.configuration.getMilliseconds("timeout")
(myActor ? GiveMeSomething)(timeout).mapTo[...]
```

but timeout is an `Option[Long]`. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Typesafe's `Config` class reads HOCON files and provides a `getDuration(path: String): Duration` method.  I guess you'd have to do all the legwork of figuring out the proper places from which to read the configuration files as [described in Play's docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I don't believe you can parse it directly as a duration value.

I usually have a helper class/method that does it for me, similar to this: http://pierreandrews.net/posts/config-scala.html

Comment: The original URL doesn't exist and users get redirected to clickbait websites.

Answer (score 2):

Play's configuration does support Duration, FiniteDuration and other Scala types. Use:

`configuration.get[FiniteDuration]("path.to.duration")`

The `Configuration.get` function takes an implicit `ConfigLoader[A]`. Play comes with a [lot of implementations](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.ConfigLoader$) and easy to add additional ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try getDuration(String, TimeUnit) method.

```scala
val timeout = config.getDuration("timeout", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

Comment: I don't think that method exists on the Play `Configuration` class. It does exist on the Typesafe `Config` class, but it returns a long.  I think the question is to get a `Duration` return type.  So one answer would be to use the `.getDuration(path: String): Duration` method on the Typesafe `Config` class.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
config.getMilliseconds("timeout").map(_.milliseconds)
```

that'll give you an `Option[Duration]`; you can get/getOrElse to get a concrete value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Duration apply method as such:

```
Duration.apply(configuration.get[String]("timeout"))
```

And then in configuration you would have something like this:

```
timeout = 15 seconds
```